# SQL Inserting from another table

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, insert-into

I am inserting data from another table that is unordered however am ordering the data in the select statement as seen below:

```
INSERT INTO idmsCBStatDet 
SELECT   
  StmNo,PageNo,TxLine,ImgStatus,ImgType,
  ImgChqNo,ImgPath,ImgIndNo,TxBranchcode,
  TxCustAccNo,Txbranchname,TxCustName,
  TxRefNo,TxCCY,TxDate,ImgNo,TxDesc,
  TxValDate,TxDebit,TxCredit,TxCustno,
  TxBalance,TxChqNo,TxIndicator,InfoDate,
  InfoAmt,InfoDesc,InfoImgNo,ImgPageClass,
  Txacentrysrno,terminal 
FROM idmsCBStatDet0262107113001 
GROUP BY StmNo,PageNo,TxLine,ImgStatus,ImgType,
  ImgChqNo,ImgPath,ImgIndNo,TxBranchcode,
  TxCustAccNo,Txbranchname,TxCustName,
  TxRefNo,TxCCY,TxDate,ImgNo,TxDesc,
  TxValDate,TxDebit,TxCredit,TxCustno,TxBalance,
  TxChqNo,TxIndicator,InfoDate,InfoAmt,InfoDesc,
  InfoImgNo,ImgPageClass,Txacentrysrno,terminal 
ORDER BY cast(txline as int) asc
```

After querying, the data is unordered having TxLine in an unordered format.

How do I ensure that the data is inserted in an ordered form

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  If you want the data in order, then use `order by cast(txline as int)` in the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am ordering the data using `order by cast(txline as int)`  but upon inserting the data when I query the data is unordered.

Comment: @munaialex . . . That is how SQL works.  Tables are inherently unordered because they represent *unordered* sets.  If you want the results of a query in a particular order, you need to use `order by` in the query.

Comment: Besides the order confusion, why are you doing a GROUP BY without using any aggregate functions (e.g. MAX, SUM, COUNT)? SELECT DISTINCT will give you the same result.

Comment: @GordonLinoff @jarlh Thanks for your help. All I had to do was remove the `order by` clause which was causing the data to be inserted in an unordered form. However, removing the `group by` clause caused the data to be inserted in an unordered form.

Comment: Again: rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** "ordered". Any "order" you see is purely a coincidence. The only (really: the only) way to get a certain order when retrieving the rows is to use an `order by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `order by` clause however retain `group by` caluse.